# CORS trouble cant solve jquery, laravel5.2

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, cors

im in trouble.
I got this.

```js
function soapRequest()
    {
        var soap_str='';
        soap_str+='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; 
        soap_str+='<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"';
        soap_str+='xmlns:ns1="https://www.pagofacil.net/st/public/Wsstransaccion/?wsdl"';
        soap_str+='xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"';
        soap_str+='xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"';
        soap_str+='xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"';
        soap_str+='xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">';
        soap_str+='<env:Body>';
        soap_str+=' <ns1:transaccion env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soapencoding">';
        soap_str+=' <param0 xsi:type="ns2:Map"><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">nombre</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">Juan A</value></item><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">apellidos</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Lopez Hernández</value></item> <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">numeroTarjeta</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">5579567890123456</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">cp</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">11560</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">cvt</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">123</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">monto</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">100</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">mesExpiracion</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">10</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">anyoExpiracion</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">15</value>       </item>       <item> <key xsi:type="xsd:string">idSucursal</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">idUsuario</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">idServicio</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:int">3</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">telefono</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">5550220910</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">celular</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">5550123456</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">calleyNumero</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Anatole France 311</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">colonia</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Polanco</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">municipio</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Miguel Hidalgo</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">estado</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Distrito Federal</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">pais</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Mexico</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">email</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">comprador@correo.com</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">param1</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">param2</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2</value>       </item>       <item>  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">param3</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">3</value>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">param4</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>       </item>       <item>         <key xsi:type="xsd:string">param5</key>         <value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>       </item>     </param0> ';
        soap_str+='</ns1:transaccion> </env:Body> </env:Envelope>';
        var str=soap_str;
        function createCORSRequest(method,url)
        {
            var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
            if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
                xhr.open(method,url,false);
            }
            else
            {
                //CORS not supported
                console.log("CORS not supported");
                alert("CORS not supported");
                xhr=null;
            }
            return xhr;
        }        
        var xhr= createCORSRequest("POST","https://www.pagofacil.net/st/public/Wsstransaccion/");
        
        alert(xhr);
        
        if(!xhr)
        {
            console.log("xhr issues");
            return;
        }

        xhr.onload = function ()
        {
            var results = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(results);
        }

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','text/xml');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:8000/");       
        alert(str);
        xhr.send(str);
    }
    soapRequest();
```

I got the following errors.
1-register:895 OPTIONS pagofacil.net/st/public/Wsstransaccion/ 500 (Internal Service Error)
2-register:895 XMLHttpRequest cannot load pagofacil.net/st/public/Wsstransaccion/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
3-register:895 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'pagofacil.net/st/public/Wsstransaccion/'.

I have tried REST, JSON Post and i got the same CORS trouble with SOAP.
I even tried to disable CORS security option on mozilla but didnt work (same error).

Im not looking for a solution here, but i wonder where can i look for. 
Thanks everybody.

Update 16-05-2016
Found this tool and got some info about this. 
https://www.pagofacil.net/st/public/Wsrtransaccion/index/format/json?method=transaccion&data[nombre]=Juan&data[apellidos]=Lopez&data[numeroTarjeta]=5579567890123456&data[cvt]=123&data[cp]=11560&data[mesExpiracion]=10&data[anyoExpiracion]=18&data[monto]=6&data[idSucursal]=60f961360ca187d533d5adba7d969d6334771370&data[idUsuario]=62ad6f592ecf2faa87ef2437ed85a4d175e73c58&data[idServicio]=3&data[email]=gadlapaz@hotmail.com&data[telefono]=5550220910&data[celular]=5550123456&data[calleyNumero]=AnatoleFrance311&data[colonia]=Polanco&data[municipio]=Migueldalgo&data[estado]=DistritoFederal&data[pais]=Mexico

In short terms pagofacil.net server wont allow CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that the server does not allow the OPTIONS request, indicating that they do not allow CORS. I have a server where CORS is enabled and running `curl 'https://...myserver.../' -I -X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8000/'`
 returns the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 14 May 2016 07:06:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=mon03; path=/
Cache-control: private
```

This basically says that "You can do POST request from any origin".

Issuing the same curl command against your server `curl 'https://www.pagofacil.net/st/public/Wsstransaccion/' -I -X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8000/'`

...returns

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error
Date: Sat, 14 May 2016 07:06:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-Length: 269
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

The "Internal Service Error" indicates that you cannot do the OPTIONS request and therefore you cannot do the CORS request you are trying to do.

If the server does not allow CORS, there is not much you can do, except requesting them to enable it, or route your call through a proxy server of your own, where you enable CORS. This server could then do the request to `pagofacil` and return the data to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, ill verify with its third party company.